# Android Images from web

Tags: javascript, android, html, salesforce

I am developing a hybrid application in android. I am trying to load external images from web. but its not loading. Internal images were working fine, when I stored it in assests->www folder.The following code I am using to load external images from web

```
<img src="http:....gif" />
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question needs more detail.  What exactly do you mean by "hybrid application" (the term is somewhat ambiguous)?  How are you showing your HTML -- are you using the platform browser, or some embedded HTML view component?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to show the Image from net,

Java Code in MainActivity

```
    myWebView = new WebView(this);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    // myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/mnt/sdcard/mayur/");
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(
            WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapters.html");
```

HTML file chapters.html in Assets folder

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope, the SampleApp.java seems to be your main activity file...that's it